# Is there any way to check connectionState on android device with ktor WebSocket lib?

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, websocket, ktor

Is there any way to check connection state on android device with ktor WebSocket lib?
I want to notify when WebSocet Connected or Disconnected.
Is there any fun with this?

this is my code :

```
    try {

        client = HttpClient() {
            install(WebSockets) {
            }
        }
        client.ws(
            method = HttpMethod.Get,
            host = "hostName", path = "/ws"
        ) {

            send(Frame.Text("SampleText"))



                for (frame in incoming) {
                    when (frame) {
                       checkFrame()
                    }

                }
            }


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "${e.message} Exception")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you received a Close Frame:

```
 when (frame) {
   is Frame.Text ->  // Do text stuff here 
   is Frame.Close -> // Socket is closing/Closed
 }
```

Or check if **DefaultClientWebSocketSession** has a closeReason:

```
if(webSocketSession?.closeReason != null) {
  // Socket closed
}
```